# Rename a sequential group of files

Tags: linux, rename

I work with Debian. I have to split a 75 GB into 1000 pieces of 75 MB. I renamed them badly starting at piece 90, and I have to solve that problem.

File section `file_89` was OK. But it followed with `file_9000` instead of the `file_90`. And from there numbering followed `file_9001`, `file_9002`, ...

Total that I have to rename from the `file_9000` to the end and pass the names to `file_90` to the end, but without losing the order they have.

I'm trying to do it with the rename command, but I can not find a viable solution.

Thank you

Comment: Try posting to https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I vote to close because this question is not written in English

Comment: What do you mean by not wanting to lose the order they have? Files don't have an ordering, just the one you are using to sort them. When you are doubting about their last modification date, I think this is not changed while executing a `rename` command.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't inform the complete range of files, let's assume you are going to rename from 9000 to 90, 9001 t0 91 and so forth until 9100. The difference we have to remove from each number is 9000 - 90 = 8910, so something like this will do the job:

```
for n in {9000..9100}; do
    mv file_${n} file_$((n - 8910))
done
```

I guess you can took from there and adapt the example to your case. I hope it helps.